# Why server time become freez in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

When i want to get the server time in javascript conitnuously why it become freez

```
setInterval(function() {
    var server_now = <?php echo time(); ?> * 1000;
    console.log("server_now = "+server_now);
})
```

why it result only

```
server_now = 1511933318000
```

Why it does not continuously update

Answer (score 1):

The php echo time will only update on page reload. It won't update using setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

php script only parse once per request, the js variable server_now is always same.

```
var time = <?=time()?>;

console.log(time);

function increment() {
    time += 10;
    console.log(time);
}

setInterval("increment()", 10 * 1000);
```

But if you would like to acquire the exact server time, there should be a server API for that purpose, and then use ajax to invoke that API.

Comment: I want continuously updated current server time. How can i get it?

Comment: @HarshwardhanSharma I have updated my answer, you should use js to do that like the code snippet above.

Comment: time is miss matching on different systems.